# Electric Oven Broiler Connection Burned Off

Tags: electrical, wiring, oven

I have looked for similar questions, but none of them seem to relate to my specific scenario. But please let me know if this question isn't appropriate here.

The connection to the broiler for my electric range oven burned off. I am trying to figure out the best course of action, and was hoping to ask a few questions here in order to help.

1. It looks like I need to buy a new broil heating element, is that the case? It doesn't sound like I can use the current connector, or replace it without risking a loose or corroded connection.
   [image: Damaged Spade Connector on Broiler]

2. I'll need to cut down the the melted wire and connect it to a new one, would a ceramic wire cap be required here?

3. What kind of wire should I get for the connection? I can't seem to find the recommended gauge or heat resistance level for an electric range like this.

[image: Damaged Wire]

Comment: Bad design to start with. You might be able to clean the heater element connection down to shiny metal. You can not use the existing slip on connection, but you could use a screw with nut to make solid connection

Comment: That's great info thanks! I'll take a look at cleaning the connection and go from there.

Comment: Good luck with the repair

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is common problem with broiler ovens. It is often caused by use of inferior quick connect spade terminals, which loosen with repeated cycles of heating and cooling, until the resistance is so high at the connection that it's dissipating more power than the heating element. It also appears PTFE (Teflon) insulated wire was used, which breaks down at a lower temperature than [glass fiber or ceramic insulation](https://www.mcmaster.com/high-temperature-wire/).

In the past, I've salvaged such appliances by replacing the wire nearest the terminal with one designed for the heat, and using a quick connect designed for high temperature, or a [crimp ring-tongue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimp_(electrical)) terminal designed for high temperature, held to the heater through the small hole with a small bolt, *lock-washer* and nut.

Obviously, the repair must be done with care to route the wires and terminals away from any metal parts... a mistake can lead to electric shock!

You might find the specialized high-temp parts at an appliance repair shop, rather than buying a reel of wire and a hundred connectors online.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I appreciate it! I'll go to an appliance part shop tomorrow and see if I can find the parts.